# LISP - Program to search a specific function through its parameters

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp, parameter-list

For a course project I got to write a program in lisp.

The program should contain the most important lisp functions, their input and output parameters and maybe optional parameters.

For example: function - first, input - list, output - object (first member of list).

The program should work in 2 different ways:

1. You give the program the name of a function and it should return the function parameters.
2. You enter function parameters and if a function with these parameters exists, it should return the name of the function.

My questions:

1. What would be the right way to approach a task like this in lisp? I think maybe a tree would be a way to handle  it? (make a tree with all functions and parameters and then write a program which handles it).
2. Does anyone have a better idea than that to approach this task? Or some suggestions where / how to start? Or Tutorials containing any info?

At the moment I'm a little lost how to start. Any help you can give would be highly appreciated.

English isn't my first language, so I hope everything is understandable.

Greetings.

Comment: Missing requirement: what is "the most important lisp functions"? Who decides which ones are more important than others, and what is the cut off: five most important? Fifteen most important? Seventy-seven most important?

Comment: There are no "output parameters" in Lisp, at least ANSI Lisp. It is pass-by-value.  Output parameters can be simulated by passing mutable objects by value, and having the function mutate them. ANSI Lisp has multiple return values; maybe that's what "output parameters" refers to. The omission of the mention of return value leads me to that suspicion.   However, the return values are not named.

Comment: As the others have noted, there are no output parameters for a function. You can pass arguments as input to the function, and I’ll also assume that you’re refuring to what the function returns or mutates as “output”. Secondly, you could create a hash-table with function names (symbols) as your keys, and parameters for those keys as your values. When those keys are searched, you can return the necessary parameters for that function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all take a look to prepare your common lisp development environment. After that I think that you should, investigate:

- create functions with [defun](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm),
- [declare types](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_type.htm).

and things like that. Ffter that take a look to two common lisp functions:

- [documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_docume.htm)
- [describe](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_descri.htm)

Here is a little example:

```
CL-USER> (defun my-sum (a b) "Add my-sum parameters A and B." (+ a b))
MY-SUM
CL-USER> (my-sum 2 3)
5 (3 bits, #x5, #o5, #b101)
CL-USER> (describe #'my-sum)
#<FUNCTION MY-SUM>
  [compiled function]


Lambda-list: (A B)
Derived type: (FUNCTION (T T) (VALUES NUMBER &OPTIONAL))
Documentation:
  Add my-sum parameters A and B.
Source form:
  (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA MY-SUM
      (A B)
    "Add my-sum parameters A and B."
    (BLOCK MY-SUM (+ A B)))
; No values
CL-USER> (documentation 'my-sum 'function)
"Add my-sum parameters A and B."
CL-USER> (defun my-sum (a b) "Add my-sum parameters A and B." (declare (type fixnum a b)) (+ a b))
WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::MY-SUM in DEFUN
MY-SUM
CL-USER> (describe #'my-sum)
#<FUNCTION MY-SUM>
  [compiled function]


Lambda-list: (A B)
Derived type: (FUNCTION (FIXNUM FIXNUM)
               (VALUES
                (INTEGER -9223372036854775808 9223372036854775806)
                &OPTIONAL))
Documentation:
  Add my-sum parameters A and B.
Source form:
  (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA MY-SUM
      (A B)
    "Add my-sum parameters A and B."
    (DECLARE (TYPE FIXNUM A B))
    (BLOCK MY-SUM (+ A B)))
; No values
```

Finally, one last tip to work with strings from the output of describe:

```
CL-USER> (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
               (describe #'my-sum))
"#<FUNCTION MY-SUM>
  [compiled function]


Lambda-list: (A B)
Derived type: (FUNCTION (FIXNUM FIXNUM)
               (VALUES
                (INTEGER -9223372036854775808 9223372036854775806)
                &OPTIONAL))
Documentation:
  Add my-sum parameters A and B.
Source form:
  (SB-INT:NAMED-LAMBDA MY-SUM
      (A B)
    \"Add my-sum parameters A and B.\"
    (DECLARE (TYPE FIXNUM A B))
    (BLOCK MY-SUM (+ A B)))
"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and these tips. After work today i will test some of these things out and will write a longer answer.

Comment: Please, if this help you consider to make this the correct answer or upvote, or update it

Answer (score 2):

At face value, the task seems to be the construction of a simple symbolic database in memory, which is searchable in two ways. Entries in the database are understood to be functions. The "output parameters" can probably be understood as one or more return values. These things are not named in ANSI Lisp. A useful interpretation of the task is to give return values symbolic labels anyway. Moreover, we can perhaps use type symbols for the return values as well as parameters. So for instance, a database entry for the *cons* function might look like:

```
(cons (t t) cons)   ;; function named cons takes two objects, returns a cons
```

The type `t` is the supertype of all types in ANSI Lisp; it means "any value".

A list of such records can be put into some global variable. Then we write a function that is perhaps named `get-params-by-name` such that:

```
(get-params-by-name 'cons) -> (t t)
```

and another one: `get-names-by-params`:

```
(get-names-by-params '(t t)) -> (cons)
```

This function returns **all** the matching functions, as a list. More than one function could have this signature.

The trick is then finding a good representation of optional and rest parameters. It could just be the same notation that the language uses:

```
(list (&rest t) list)   ;; list takes rest arguments of any type, returns list
```

Since we are only interested in exact matches, we don't have to actually parse the `&rest` notation. When the user queries by parameter, their query object will be literally `(&rest t)`, in that same syntax.

The `equal` function can be used to tell whether two lists of symbols are identical:

```
(equal '(&rest t) '(&rest t)) -> t
(equal '(t t) '(t t)) -> nil
```

So the exercise is not difficult: just mapping through lists, looking for matches.

```
(defun get-name-by-params (database params)
  (let ((matching-entries (remove-if-not (lambda (entry)
                                            (equal (second entry) params))
                                          database)))
    (mapcar #'first matching-entries))) ;; just the names, please
```

Here, the function takes the database list as a parameter, instead of referring to a global variable. The overall program into which we integrate this can provide alternative interfaces, but this is our low-level lookup function.

Test:

```
[1]> (get-name-by-params '((cons (t t) cons) (list (&rest t) list)) '(integer string))
NIL
[3]> (get-name-by-params '((cons (t t) cons) (list (&rest t) list)) '(t t))
(CONS)
[4]> (get-name-by-params '((cons (t t) cons) (list (&rest t) list)) '(&rest t))
(LIST)
```

I'd get clarification from the instructor whether this is the right interpretation of the vague requirements, before the assignment is due.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps. I think this is exactly what i need for the project. What function are important is left up to us. So the next step would be to create the database for all functions i want to include in this, right?

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a course project I'm going to provide an incomplete answer, and leave you to fill in the blanks.

### What the program should do

My interpretation of what you're being asked to do is to provide a utility which will

- given the name of a function return its argument list (called a 'lambda list' below);
- given a lambda list return all the functions with that lambda list.

So, first of all you need to decide whether two lambda lists are the same or not.  As an example is `(x)` the same as `(y)`, as a lambda list?  Yes, it is: the names of formal parameters only matter in the implementation of a function and you generally won't know them: both of these lambda lists mean 'function of one argument'.

The interestring thing is optional arguments of various kinds: `(a &optional b)` is clearly not the same as `(a)`, but is the same as `(b &optional c)` but is it the same as `(a &optional (b 1 bp))`?  In this code I say that yes, it is the same: default values and present parameters for optional arguments don't alter whether lambda lists are the same.  That's because very often these are implementation details of functions.

### A package

We'll put it into a package so it's clear what the interface is:

```
(defpackage :com.stackoverflow.lisp.fdesc-search
  (:use :cl)
  (:export
   #:defun/recorded
   #:record-function-description
   #:clear-recorded-functions
   #:name->lambda-list
   #:lambda-list->names))

(in-package :com.stackoverflow.lisp.fdesc-search)
```

### Recording information

So, to start with we need a mechanism of recording information about functions.  We'll do this with a macro which is like `defun` but records information, which I'll call `defun/recorded`.  We want to be able to record information about things *even before the program exists* & we do this by having `defun/recorded` stash 'pending' records on a list which, once the program exists, it will pull off and record properly.  That lets us use `defun/recorded` throughout this code.

```
;;; These define whether there is a recorder, and if not where pending
;;; records should be stashed
;;;
(defvar *function-description-recorder* nil)
(defvar *pending-function-records* '())

(defmacro defun/recorded (name lambda-list &body forms)
  "Like DEFUN but record function information."
  ;; This deals with bootstrapping by, if there is not yet a recording
  ;; function, stashing pending records in *PENDING-FUNCTION-RECORDS*,
  ;; which gets replayed into the recorder at the point it becomes
  ;; available.
  `(progn
     ;; do the DEFUN first, which ensures that the LAMBDA-LIST is OK
     (defun ,name ,lambda-list ,@forms)
     (if *function-description-recorder*
         (progn
           (dolist (p (reverse *pending-function-records*))
             (funcall *function-description-recorder*
                      (car p) (cdr p)))
           (setf *pending-function-records* '())
           (funcall *function-description-recorder*
                    ',name ',lambda-list))
       (push (cons ',name ',lambda-list)
             *pending-function-records*))
     ',name))
```

### Matching lambda lists, first steps

Now we want to be able to match lambda lists.  Since we're obviously going to store things indexed by lambda list in some kind of tree we only really need to be able to deal with matching *elements* of them.  And (see above) we don't care about things like default values.  I've chosen to do this by first of all simplifying lambda lists to remove them and then matching the simplifies elements: there are other approaches.

`simplify-lambda-list` does the simplification and `argument-matches-p` tells you if two arguments match: the interesting bit is that it needs to know about lambda list keywords, which must match exactly, while everything else matches anything.  The `lambda-list-keywords` constant is conveniently provided by the CL standard.

```
(defun/recorded simplify-lambda-list (ll)
  ;; Simplify a lambda list by replacing optional arguments with inits
  ;; by their names.  This does not validate the list
  (loop for a in ll
        collect (etypecase a
                  (symbol a)
                  (list (first a)))))

(defun/recorded argument-matches-p (argument prototype)
  ;; Does an argument match a prototype.
  (unless (symbolp argument)
    (error "argument ~S isn't a symbol" argument))
  (unless (symbolp prototype)
    (error "prototype ~S isn't a symbol" prototype))
  (if (find-if (lambda (k)
                 (or (eq argument k) (eq prototype k)))
               lambda-list-keywords)
      (eq argument prototype)
    t))
```

### Function descriptions (partial)

Information about functions is stored in objects called `fdesc`s: the definition of these objects is not given here, but one question we need to answer is 'do two `fdesc`s refer to versions of the same function?'  Well, they do if the names of the functions are the same.  Remember that function names do not have to be symbols (`(defun (setf x) (...) ...)` is allowed), so we must compare with `equal` not `eql`:

```
(defun/recorded fdescs-equivalent-p (fd1 fd2)
  ;; do FD1 & FD2 refer to the same function?
  (equal (fdesc-name fd1)
         (fdesc-name fd2)))
```

### Storing `fdesc`s indexed by lambda list (partial)

To index things efficiently by lambda list we build a tree.  The nodes in this tree are called `lambda-list-tree-node`s and their definition is not given here.

There are functions which intern a `fdesc` in a tree, and which return a list of `fdesc`s indexed by a given lambda list.  Neither have an implementation here, but this is what they look like:

```
(defun/recorded intern-lambda-list (lambda-list tree-node fdesc)
  ;; return the node where it was interned
  ...)

(defun/recorded lambda-list-fdescs (lambda-list tree-node)
  ;; Return a list of fdescs for a lambda list & T if there were any
  ;; or NIL & NIL if there were not (I don't think () & T is possible,
  ;; but it might be in some future version)
  ...)
```

The implementation of these functions will probably need to use use `argument-matches-p` and `fdescs-equivalent-p`.

### The top-level databases (slightly partial)

Now we can define the top-level database objects: the root of the tree for indexing by lambda list, and a hashtable for indexing by name

```
(defvar *lambda-list-tree* (make-lambda-list-tree-node))

(defvar *tree-nodes-by-name* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
```

Note that `*tree-nodes-by-name*` maps from names to *the node where the information about that function is stored*: that's done to make redefinition easier, as seen in the following function:

```
(defun/recorded record-function-description (name lambda-list)
  "Record information about a function called NAME with lambda list LAMBDA-LIST.
Replace any existing information abot NAME.  Return NAME."
  (let ((fdesc (make-fdesc :name name :lambda-list lambda-list)))
    ;; First of all remove any existing information
    (multiple-value-bind (node foundp) (gethash name *tree-nodes-by-name*)
      (when foundp
        (setf (lambda-list-tree-node-values node)
              (delete fdesc (lambda-list-tree-node-values node)
                      :test #'fdescs-equivalent-p))))
    (setf (gethash name *tree-nodes-by-name*)
          (intern-lambda-list lambda-list *lambda-list-tree* fdesc)))
  name)
```

Note that this function first of all looks up any existing information for `name`, and if it exists it removes it from the node where it was found.  This makes sure that function redefinition does not leave obsolete information in the tree.

This function is the actual recorder which `defun/recorded` wants to know about, so tell it that:

```
(setf *function-description-recorder*
      #'record-function-description)
```

Now the next time we invoke `defun/recorded` it will bootstrap the system by inserting all the the pending definitions.

`record-function-description` is part of the API to the package: it can be used to record information about functions we don't define.

### User-interface functions

Apart from `defun/recorded` & `record-function-description` we want some functions which let us make enquiries into the database, as well as one which resets things:

```
(defun/recorded clear-recorded-functions ()
  "Clear function description records.  Return no values"
  (setf *lambda-list-tree* (make-lambda-list-tree-node)
        *tree-nodes-by-name* (make-hash-table :test #'equal))
  (values))

(defun/recorded name->lambda-list (name)
  "Look up a function by name.
Return either its lambda list & T if it is found, or NIL & NIL if not."
  (multiple-value-bind (node foundp) (gethash name *tree-nodes-by-name*)
    (if foundp
        (values
         (fdesc-lambda-list
          (find-if (lambda (fd)
                     (equal (fdesc-name fd) name))
                   (lambda-list-tree-node-values node)))
         t)
      (values nil nil))))

(defun/recorded lambda-list->names (lambda-list)
  "find function names matching a lambda-list.
Return a list of name & T if there are any, or NIL & NIL if none.

Note that lambda lists are matched so that argument names do not match, and arguments with default values or presentp parameters match just on the argument."
  (multiple-value-bind (fdescs foundp) (lambda-list-fdescs lambda-list 
                                                           *lambda-list-tree*)
    (if foundp
        (values (mapcar #'fdesc-name fdescs) t)
      (values nil nil))))
```

And that's it.

### Examples

After compiling, loading & using the package (with the missing bits added) we can first inject some useful extra functions into it (this is just a random scattering)

```
> (dolist (x '(car cdr null))
    (record-function-description x '(thing)))
nil

> (dolist (x '(car cdr))
    (record-function-description `(setf ,x) '(new thing)))
nil

> (record-function-description 'cons '(car cdr))
cons

> (record-function-description 'list '(&rest args))
```

Now we can make some enquiries:

```
 > (lambda-list->names '(x))
 (null cdr
       car
       lambda-list->names
       name->lambda-list
       com.stackoverflow.lisp.fdesc-search::simplify-lambda-list)
t

> (lambda-list->names '(&rest anything))
(list)
t
 > (name->lambda-list 'cons)
 (car cdr)
 t
```

---

### An example of storing things in trees

Below is some code which demonstrates one approach to storing information in trees (often known as [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)).  *This is not usable above* for a lot of reasons, but reading it might help implement the missing parts.

```
;;;; Storing things in trees of nodes
;;;

;;; Node protocol
;;;
;;; Nodes have values which may or may not be bound, and which may be
;;; assigned.  Things may be interned in (trees of) nodes with a
;;; value, and the value associated with a thing may be retrieved
;;; along with an indicator as to whether it is present in the tree
;;; under the root.
;;;

(defgeneric node-value (node)
  ;; the immediate value of a node
  )

(defgeneric (setf node-value) (new node)
  ;; Set the immediate value of a node
  )

(defgeneric node-value-boundp (node)
  ;; Is a node's value bound?
  )

(defgeneric intern-thing (root thing value)
  ;; intern a thing in a root, returning the value
  (:method :around (root thing value)
   ;; Lazy: this arround method just makes sure that primary methods
   ;; don't need to beother returning the value
   (call-next-method)
   value))

(defgeneric thing-value (root thing)
  ;; return two values: the value of THING in ROOT and T if is it present, or
  ;; NIL & NIL if not
  )


;;; Implementatation for STRING-TRIE-NODEs, which store strings
;;;
;;; The performance of these will be bad if large numbers of strings
;;; with characters from a large alphabet are stored: how might you
;;; fix this without making the nodes enormous?
;;;

(defclass string-trie-node ()
  ;; a node in a string trie.  This is conceptually some kind of
  ;; special case of an abstract 'node' class, but that doesn't
  ;; actually exist.
  ((children-map :accessor string-trie-node-children-map
                 :initform '())
   (value :accessor node-value)))

(defmethod node-value-boundp ((node string-trie-node))
  (slot-boundp node 'value))

(defmethod intern-thing ((root string-trie-node) (thing string) value)
  ;; intern a string into a STRING-TRIE-NODE, storing VALUE
  (let ((pmax (length thing)))
    (labels ((intern-loop (node p)
               (if (= p pmax)
                   (setf (node-value node) value)
                 (let ((next-maybe (assoc (char thing p) 
                                          (string-trie-node-children-map node)
                                          :test #'char=)))
                   (if next-maybe
                       (intern-loop (cdr next-maybe) (1+ p))
                     (let ((next (cons (char thing p)
                                       (make-instance (class-of node)))))
                       (push next (string-trie-node-children-map node))
                       (intern-loop (cdr next) (1+ p))))))))
      (intern-loop root 0))))

(defmethod thing-value ((root string-trie-node) (thing string))
  ;; Return the value associated with a string in a node & T or NIL &
  ;; NIL if there is no value for this string
  (let ((pmax (length thing)))
    (labels ((value-loop (node p)
               (if (= p pmax)
                   (if (node-value-boundp node)
                       (values (node-value node) t)
                     (values nil nil))
                 (let ((next (assoc (char thing p)
                                    (string-trie-node-children-map node)
                                    :test #'char=)))
                   (if next
                       (value-loop (cdr next) (1+ p))
                     (values nil nil))))))
      (value-loop root 0))))


;;; Draw node trees in LW
;;;

#+LispWorks
(defgeneric graph-node-tree (node))
  (:method ((node string-trie-node))
   (capi:contain
    (make-instance 'capi:graph-pane
                   :roots `((nil . ,node))
                   :children-function (lambda (e)
                                        (string-trie-node-children-map (cdr e)))
                   :edge-pane-function (lambda (pane parent child)
                                         (declare (ignore pane parent))
                                         (make-instance
                                          'capi:labelled-line-pinboard-object
                                          :text (format nil "~A" (car child))))
                   :print-function (lambda (n)
                                     (let ((node (cdr n)))
                                       (format nil "~A"
                                               (if (node-value-boundp node)
                                                   (node-value node)
                                                 ""))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your amazing work. I would really like to work with the program and try out changes in the code, but at the moment, i got not the slightest idea what code to add in the partial answers to make it work. Is there any chance you could send me the partial code so i can use a first working version of the program for additional testing and creating an own solution for the task?

Comment: @Amduscias: I have added some example code of building and searching trees/tries.  *This can't be used as is*, anywhere near, but it may provide you with a hint as to how you might build & search trees.  Another hint: when interning lists in trees *don't repeatedly index into the list*: there's a better way.